# Android LocationListener- requestLocationUpdates

Tags: java, android, location

I try to get my current location. First I created LocationListener:

```
 public LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            // Getting latitude of the current location
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            // Getting longitude of the current location
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
            myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        }
    };
```

The in onCreate method I try to cal requestLocatonUpates on LocationManager:

```
 mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
       mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,500f,mLocationListener);
```

But I get an error:

Cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates(java.langString, long, float,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)

Comment: Try to pass android.location.LocationListener, not google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

Answer (score 0):

requestLocationUpdates is a method provided in FusedLocationAPi. You should use LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates method. 
So you have to create a googleApiClient and a location request.
You can found it here : https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html.